# C++ Bitset << operator not working. Pointer to bitset variable

Tags: c++, pointers, bitset, bit-shift

I have a set of bitsets pointers in an unordered_map

```
static unordered_map< size_t, bitset<BITSIZE>* > systemBits;
```

And my function

```
template<typename system>
     static bitset<BITSIZE> & getBitFor() {

    size_t hash = typeid(system).hash_code();

    bitset<BITSIZE> * bit = systemBits[hash];

    if(bit == NULL) {
        bit = new bitset<BITSIZE>(0);
        (*bit) << POS++; // tried *bit << POS++ as well;
        systemBits[hash] = bit;
    }

    return *bit;
}
```

Whereas POS is an int set to 1 at first.

All that I'm trying to do is shift the bitset with the amounts of position per new bitset.

```
 (*bit) << POS++;
```

However this doesn't seem to work. When I *cout* the returned bitset all its bits are set to 0.
If I do to the following:

```
bit->flip();
```

or
   (*bit).flip();

The bitset returned does flip all the 0 to 1.

What gives? Why does the shift operator have no effect at all?

Comment: Obvious question: is POS equal to 0?

Comment: Even so, I'm calling the function twice on two different object.
So it should at least print one bitset with 1 shift. But no. POS = 1;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're not assigning the result to anything . You'd have the same problem if you were trying to shift an int.

Also, you've initialized your bitset to zero, and zero shifted by any amount is always zero.

Comment: Why does it need assignment? I'm working with the bitset directly.

Comment: @sidar for the same reason that int i= 3; i<< 2; doesn't do anything.

Comment: Well that was majorly lame. (*bit)  = 1 << POS++; did the trick. Now I'm limited to the bit size of a number type though. Need to use a nother bitset then. Thanks mate.